# Depth First Search: Given a set of letters construct valid words

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

Lets say I have a set of letters {a, b, c, t} and a function dictionary(s) that returns T/F to check if a string s exists in the English dictionary. Construct valid words using Depth First Search.

I am not asking for any code here. I need some help with the tree structure. I am not able to visualise the tree structure in this problem.

For example these four letters can be in one single column for s DFS. So do I have to construct the tree for all possible permutations and then perform a DFS ?

Edit: I need to construct words of size 3.

Example:

```
        a               b
       /               /
      b               c
     /               /
    c               t
   /               /
  t               a
```

Comment: It is not necessary to explicitly represent the tree; just suppose that each letter is valid in each position. If I understand the question correctly, the problem makes no sense without a restriction on the length of the words.

Comment: @Codor: Thanks for the comment. You are right. I need to construct words of size 3. If the problem is asking me for a DFS approach, then I think its right that I should be able to draw the tree structure as well.
I can solve this using brute force as well, but I want to use DFS and hence need to visualize the tree structure.

Comment: The tree structure would have a root with empty string `''`. At every step depthwise you pick a letter from the available letters. That means 4 children of root and 3 children each for nodes at depth 1, 2 children each for nodes at depth 2. Total leaf nodes is `4 x 3 x 2` which is also equal to `4P3`. You should check T/F whenever you reach a leaf node (that is when you actually have a word)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps. I now understand how this search would work.

Answer (score 0):

**Tree Structure:**

You can build a tree with each node representing a letter in the alphabet.  A node would potentially link to all the letters of the alphabet.

**Load Dicitionary:**

Load words and build tree. Each letter from word would cause us to walk through tree starting from root. If we hit a *null* in one of the links, then create new node.

**Usage**:

Then just fall through the first link until you hit an *endOfWord* flag, which would signal a word.

```
typedef struct {
   char *letter[ 26 ];
   bool endOfWord;
}
```

Root node would be null as starting point.

Comment: You would want to have  a separate flag to mark the end of a word rather than a NULL node so that words can be prefixes of longer words. Hence "prefix tree".

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst Thanks! I had a flag in the struct to mark end of words but removed due to probably lack of sleep. Corrected!